# Why we want to convert a voltmeter to an ammeter or vice versa?

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement

Why in laboratory experiments do we want to convert a voltmeter to an ammeter and vice versa? What is our main aim here that is for what we are doing it?

If our goal was to change the range of the meters, then we could do the same by converting an ammeter to another ammeter or a  voltmeter  to another voltmeter. Then why are we doing this type of conversion, for what?

Comment: Voltmeters **are** ammeters they determing the voltage by measuring the small current that passes through a known high resistance then calculating the voltage using $V = IR$.

Comment: @JohnRennie I would guess modern ammeters are actually voltmeters using a small resistor and a field effect transistor and a analog to digital converter to measure the voltage rather directly. But good old moving coil galvanometers are most certainly ammeters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving coil instruments are pure current measurement devices: The coil is inside a magnetic field, so a current will cause a momentum on it. As the coil can move, it follows this momentum, but there is also a spring generating a counter-momentum. So, the coil only turns by a certain angle, which depends on the current. A needle attached to the coil allows to read the current corresponding to that angle.

If you want to measure voltage, you can put a resistor in series with the instrument. The voltage causes a certain current, which is then measured.

---

On the other side, the measurement device inside a digital multimeter (DMM) is a pure voltage measurement device.

If you want to measure currents, you put a resistor in the line and measure the voltage drop across it.

---

The point about ranges is that a device usually has a certain range. You need a circuit to map the input range and type (voltage, current) to the range and type accepted by the measurement device.

---

Finally, your question is:

> Why in laboratory experiments do we want to convert a voltmeter to an ammeter and vice versa? What is our main aim here that is for what we are doing it?

First, I hope you know the difference between voltage and current, and that you usually can not get the one from the other. You you definitely want to be able to measure both.

Usually, you don't have a Voltmeter or Ammeter, but a device where you can select the input type and range. So usually no need to convert it yourself!

Sometimes, you can not measure the type you desire. For example, there is no way to put your Ammeter into a track onto a PCB. In this case, you may be able to measure the voltage drop on a resistor on your PCB and convert it to current yourself.

I remember we had a pure Ammeter, which can measure some picoAmpere with a high precision. 
If you want to measure a few microVolt, a standard voltmeter may not be able to measure it precisely. But this Ammeter would be, if you convert it to a Voltmeter by a resistor.

However, you may have converted your device yourself during a practical course to learn how it works. And each device has some disadvantages (Voltmeters should not draw current, but they do. Ammeters should not drop voltage, but they do), and you may have investigated this during a course.

Answer (score 2):

They teach you to convert voltmeter to an ammeter and back so that you know how to indirectly measure current or voltage. It is more useful measuring current though.

Also, you can build an ohmmeter using a power supply, a known resistor and a voltmeter.

Examples from my practice:

- Measuring current without disconnecting the circuit.

I need to measure the current flowing trough a tube in my amp, but do not want to disconnect the power to connect the multimeter (st to amps range). I can measure the voltage on the cathode resistor and calculate the current. This makes measuring the power dissipated in the tube much faster (measure voltage between anode and cathode, measure voltage on the cathode resistor, calculate the current, multiply to get power) than if I needed to disconnect the power, desolder the cathode resistor and splice the ammeter in series.

- Measuring higher currents than your meter is capable

I needed to measure the current flowing from my car alternator (up to 150A), but my meter can only measure up to 10A. I did it like this:

First, I measured the resistance of the wire between alternator and battery. I did this by connecting a known load (a lighbulb) between alternator post and ground when the engine was stopped and measuring the voltage drop.
Then, I measured the voltage drop on the wire when the engine was on and calculated the current from the voltage drop and resistance. I got around 70A which would have melted my meter (and not given me any result other than "way above 10A") if I tried measuring the current directly.

The ohmmeter can also be useful.

- Measure the leakage resistance of a capacitor

Most modern multimeters use low voltage to measure resistance. That is not enough when measuring leakage resistance of a capacitor which usually shows up only with higher voltages. So, I connected a 24V power supply, the capacitor under test and a 1M resistor. Then I waited a bit for the cap to charge and measured the voltage across the resistor and calculated the current (I could have measured current directly here, but my meter does not measure microamps). Then I measured the voltage across the capacitor and calculated the leakage resistance from the voltage and current.

These are all things that I actually did and had to know how to make an ammeter and ohmmeter from a voltmeter and external components.